# replace all negative value from array using recursion C

Tags: c++, c, recursion

I want replace all negative value by zero(recursively). And I have use C and recursion. It's was my homework.

Desired output:
0 4 0 3

What I get:

0 4 -9 3

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int zeros_value(int n, int tab[])
{
    if (n==0) return 0;
    if(tab[n-1] < 0){
       tab[n-1]=0;
    }
    else{ 
        return zero_value(n-1,tab);
    }
```

}

```
int main(void)
{
  int tab[4] = {0,4,-9,3};
  int number = 0;
  int i;
  zero_value(4, tab);
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
      printf("%d ", tab[i]);



  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Also you need to explain what you want this program to do?

Comment: Avoid printf, until you get familiar with std::cout and argument types (printf has valid use cases).

Comment: And, what is returned when the condition `tab[n-1] < 0` is true?

Comment: Dear Ben, I want subsitute all negative numbers by zero(recursively).

Comment: If this isn't a kind of homework I would refrain from using a recursion here, iterate over the array.

Comment: you can not do this `printf("%d%d%d%d", zeros_value(4,tab));` printf expects 3 more argumens, you are providing only one

Comment: C++ and C are different languages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you hit the first negative, the recursion doesn't continue anymore and the function returns. You don't really need to return any value from the function. You can rewrite it to make a `void` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void zero_value(int n, int tab[])
{
  if (n==0) return;
  if(tab[n-1] < 0) tab[n-1]=0;
  zero_value(n-1,tab);
}

int main(void)
{
  int tab[4] = {0,4,-9,3};
  int number = 0;
  int i;

  zero_value(4, tab);

  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  printf("%d ", tab[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the following problems with your code.

1. The function `zero_values` does not have a valid `return` statement when `tab[n-1]` is negative. You can see it more clearly if you change the function to:

   ```
   int zeros_value(int n, int tab[])
   {
     if (n==0)
     {
        return 0;
     }

     if(tab[n-1] < 0)
     {
        tab[n-1]=0;
        // No return here.
     }
     else
     {
        return zero_value(n-1,tab);
     }

     // No return here either.
   }
   ```

   Calling such functions leads undefined behavior.
2. The `printf` line in `main` is not right.

   ```
   printf("%d%d%d%d", zeros_value(4,tab));
   ```

   That line needs four arguments of type `int` after the format string to work correctly. Not providing enough arguments to `printf` is also cause for undefined behavior.

You can use solution provided in [the answer by @usr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34752403/434551) to solve both problems.

If you have any valid reasons to return an `int` from `zero_value`, you need to change the implementation appropriately. It's not clear from your post what that return value is supposed to be.